# Deseo abrir un procedimiento en sql server managment por medio del código

Tags: sql, stored-procedure, sql-server-management

Si usas Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio, debo seguir los siguientes pasos.

1. Servidor
2. Databases
3. (Seleccionas tu base de datos)
4. Programmability Stored
5. Procedures
6. (Buscas tu SP)

¿Existe una forma más rápida de abrir un procedimiento ya sabiendo cual es el nombre?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. Solo acotar que los procedimientos almacenados no se "abren". Puedes ver el código y el SSMS te permite _"editarlos"_, de la manera que has descrito; nada impide escribir directamente una sentencia `alter procedure` directamente en el editor.

Answer (score 1):

Conociendo el nombre exacto y eventualmente el owner (si fuera distinto al usuario con el que estás conectado) puedes usar [`sp_helptext()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helptext-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) de la siguiente forma:

```
EXEC sp_helptext 'nombre_del_sp_funcion_o_trigger 

--- En caso de necesitar indicar el owner
EXEC sp_helptext 'usuario.nombre_del_sp_funcion_o_trigger
```

---

- Esta llamada retorna como resultado el código completo del `sp`
- En el SQL management debes asegurarte que los resultados sean en modo texto (sino puedes perder los tabuladores si los tienes)
- Finalmente copias los resultados en una nueva ventana de consulta y ya tienes disponible el código para eventualmente modificarlo.